# How can I search for the full name if there are 3 different field name in the database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have three different columns the first_name, middle_name, and last_name. I combined the three columns to one as a full name. The problem is when I search for a full name or even the other field names like username it gives me an empty or blank table. When I remove the 3 fieldname in my select there is no output for my full name column and the rest of the field names is ok. I want to combine the three field names so whenever the user search for it appears as one. It is possible to combine three field names and search it as one column? This is my query below.

```
  public function searchUser($keyword) {
        $sql = "SELECT tbl_user.user_id, 
                       tbl_user.username, 
                       (tbl_user.first_name + tbl_user.middle_name + tbl_user.lastname), 
                       tbl_barangay.barangay_name 
               FROM tbl_user 
               INNER JOIN tbl_barangay 
                 ON tbl_barangay.barangay_id = tbl_user.barangay_id 
               WHERE username LIKE :keyword 
                 OR first_name LIKE :keyword 
                 OR last_name LIKE :keyword 
                 OR middle_name LIKE :keyword 
                 OR barangay_name LIKE :keyword";

        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->execute([
            ":keyword" => '%' . $keyword . '%'
        ]);

        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }
```

Comment: You look for `CONCAT`

Comment: MySQL doesn't use `+` for string concatenation, you have to write `CONCAT(first_name, middle_name, lastname)`. Also see `CONCAT_WS`, which allows you to specify a separator between each of the columns (so you get spaces between each name).

Comment: Also add a column alias for the `CONCAT_WS`, such as `CONCAT_WS(first_name, middle_name, lastname) AS FullName`

Comment: The problem when I search for exact field names it's given me an empty table

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use VIEW for this. create a view that combines the three fields to be fullname. then point your query to that VIEW. or you can just use CONCAT function to put a condition to your combined fields. See query below:

```
SELECT tbl_user.user_id, 
       tbl_user.username, 
       CONCAT(tbl_user.first_name,' ',tbl_user.middle_name,' ',tbl_user.lastname) as fullname, 
       tbl_barangay.barangay_name 
FROM tbl_user 
INNER JOIN bl_barangay ON tbl_barangay.barangay_id = tbl_user.barangay_id
WHERE username LIKE :keyword OR 
      barangay_name LIKE :keyword OR 
      CONCAT(tbl_user.first_name,' ',tbl_user.middle_name,' ',tbl_user.lastname) LIKE :keyword
```

Note: You can change the sequence of field names from CONCAT

Comment: I use this query but still, the full name is not displaying when I search for the specific row  
`SELECT tbl_user.user_id, tbl_user.username, tbl_user.password, CONCAT(tbl_user.first_name,' ',tbl_user.middle_name,' ',tbl_user.last_name) as Fullname,tbl_barangay.barangay_name FROM tbl_user INNER JOIN tbl_barangay ON tbl_barangay.barangay_id = tbl_user.barangay_id HAVING username LIKE :keyword OR Fullname LIKE :keyword OR barangay_name LIKE :keyword`